# How to get the cell above in a table using XPath?

Tags: xpath, xidel

I'm trying to put all the info about each cell in a table in a single line. And I need to figure out how to print the header of each column in the table.

```css
td, table {
  border: 2px black solid;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>a1</td>
    <td>a2</td>
    <td>a3</td>
    <td>a4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>b1</td>
    <td>b2</td>
    <td>b3</td>
    <td>b4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>c1</td>
    <td>c2</td>
    <td>c3</td>
    <td>c4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>d1</td>
    <td>d2</td>
    <td>d3</td>
    <td>d4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

```
Table 1
+----+----+----+----+
| a1 | a2 | a3 | a4 |
+----+----+----+----+
| b1 | b2 | b3 | b4 |
+----+----+----+----+
| c1 | c2 | c3 | c4 |
+----+----+----+----+
| d1 | d2 | d3 | d4 |
+----+----+----+----+

Table 2
+----+----+----+----+
| e1 | e2 | e3 | e4 |
+----+----+----+----+
| f1 | f2 | f3 | f4 |
+----+----+----+----+
| g1 | g2 | g3 | g4 |
+----+----+----+----+
| h1 | h2 | h3 | h4 |
+----+----+----+----+

And Other Tables ...
```

I want to get the cells printed with the cell at the top of the column (i.e. tr[1]).

The output shouldn't have the first raw ..

The first output should be:

The cell b1 has the header a1

..

The cell g2 has the header e2

and so on ..

I'm using xidel:

`xidel $site -e "//tr[position()>1]/td/concat('The cell ', ., $codeX)"`

What the value of `$codeX` should be?

Thanks,

Comment: If you want to use the first row then it sounds as if using `//tr[1]/td` is what you want

Comment: @MartinHonnen I want to get it from the second row, actually I am using concat() to print them together.

Answer (score 2):

Xidel supports XQuery 3.0 so for structuring the task I would suggest e.g.

```
let $rows := //tr,
    $header-cells := $rows[1]/td
for $data-row in $rows[position() gt 1]
for $cell at $pos in $data-row/td
return $cell!('cell ' || . || ' has header ' || $header-cells[$pos])
```

Not sure whether that works well from the command line but does the job.

Comment: This can be done simpler: `for $row in //tr[position()>1] for $cell at $i in $row/td return concat('cell ',$cell,' has header ',//tr[1]/td[$i])`.

Answer (score 1):

You may use only xpath for get it:

```
//table//tr[1]/td[count(//table//td[text()='${cellValue}']/preceding-sibling::*) + number(boolean(//table//td[text()='${cellValue}']/preceding-sibling::*))]
```

> Note:
>   specifying cell which contains existing value (e.g. 'b3') gives a correct cell from header ('a3').
>   If you trying to search invalid value of cell you receiving a correct empty value because of cell in the header is not exist.

Answer (score 0):

**To get table header tex**t just get 1st tr data `//tr[1]/td` or `//tr[1]/th` if tag `th` used for header (which is expected)

**To get header by column text** try this XPath on that table: https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_table_border

```
//th[count(//tr/td[text()='Griffin'])]
```

Logic is: find position of `td` with specific text `//tr/td[text()='Griffin']`, by using `count()` function. And just find `th` by this position

Comment: I tried to do this with '../../tr[1]/td[count(./preceding-sibling::td)]'
and it didn't work

Comment: have you tried what i suggested? because your locator is 100% incorrect

Comment: How should I find the text inside the td element? Actually I have a lot of tables and a lot of cells and also my post is over simplified.

Comment: Actually I have modified my question. I hope it is more comprehensible. Your help is appreciated.

Comment: please also add tables html, headers inside th tag or td?

Comment: I have added the first example table as html.